# Flutter change Textfield selected background color

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, textfield

I have a `TextField` which looks like this at the moment:

[image]

As you can see the selected color is purple. But how can I change that color for that specific `TextField` ? I **do not** want to change the `AppThemeData`. I couldn't find anything on this ... Happy for every help!

Answer (score 0):

you can try and wrap it with `Theme` and use `SplashColor` to be something like this :

```
Theme(
  data: ThemeData(textSelectionColor: Colors.green),
  child: TextField(
    autofocus: false,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      filled: true,
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      hintText: 'Mail',
     
    ),
  ),
);
```

or do this in main :

````
theme: ThemeData(
          accentColor: Color(0xffBA379B).withOpacity(.6),
          primaryColor: Color(0xffBA379B),
          textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
            selectionColor: Color(0xffBA379B).withOpacity(.5),
            cursorColor: Color(0xffBA379B).withOpacity(.6),
            selectionHandleColor: Color(0xffBA379B).withOpacity(1),
          ),
    ```
````

Comment: that is not working for me. I do not want to change the `fillColor`. I want to change the copy/selected color. The purple color in the picture appears when selecting the text

Comment: i have updated my answer , is this working ?

Comment: `textSelectionColor` is deprecated :(

Comment: do the main.dart